# Linking weather widget

Tags: android

I want to link the weather widget with my application.First i want to place that icon on the top right corner of my application .How should i do that.I am trying this with the help of setfeaturedrawableresource , but it's not working?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could write your solution here for other pwople to see.